# Why are the colors from color ramps dimmer than what you pick?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, color, color-management

If I input a color in a color ramp, and set the ramp to constant, the colors do not come out exactly like the input. They are grayer/darker.

Example:

On my color ramp, the yellow input is "#FFF763", but the output is "#cecb6d"

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default blender tweaks the final renders colors.

Go to the **Render Properties** tab (camera), and under **Color Management**, change **View Transform** from **Filmic** to **Standard**. Now the colors will come out nearly identical.